# Return array if values on one array exist in another array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays that hold some numbers

```
 All Mateys 

          [{
         'names':'Lot',
         'number':'0800695828'
           },
           {
          'names':'Voltaire',
          'number':'0800069005'
          }]


Invited Mateys ["0800695828", "0800069005"]
```

All Mateys array hold a big list of names and numbers of members while invited mateys holds only numbers of members invited.

I want to use invited mateys array numbers to  create an array with names and number from the array all mateys. In short, i want to return an array holding names and a numbers with a number present in invited arrays.

I can iterate invited mateys like so

```
for(var i = 0; i < invited_mateys.length; i++){
      var invited_matey_number = invited_mateys[i];
      console.log(invited_matey_number);
      //search for this number in all mateys and create an arrr
      }
```

How would I search and create an array with names and number?

Comment: I think you need to `filter` all mateys by invited mateys, correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `filter()` and `indexOf()` to check if number exists in second array.

```js
var arr1 = [{
  'names': 'Lot',
  'number': '0800695828'
}, {
  'names': 'Voltaire',
  'number': '0800069005'
}]

var arr2 = ["0800695828", "0800069005"]

var result = arr1.filter(function(o) {
  return arr2.indexOf(o.number) != -1
})
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it with jQuery:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
 var All_Mateys = [{'names':'Lot','number':'0800695828'},{'names':'Voltaire','number':'0800069005'}];
 var Invited_Mateys = ["0800695828", "0800069005"];
 var final_array = [];
 for(var key in All_Mateys){
    if($.inArray(All_Mateys[key]['number'],Invited_Mateys)!==-1){
       final_array.push(All_Mateys[key]);
    }
 }
 console.log(final_array);
</script>
```

Just loop through `All_Mateys` and match each number with numbers present in `Invited_Mateys`, if you find match then insert the full sub array into new result array.

*I hope it helps*

Answer (score 1):

```js
var superset = [{
         'names':'Lot',
         'number':'0800695828'
           },
           {
          'names':'Voltaire',
          'number':'0800069005'
          }];

var subset = ["0800695828", "0800069005"];

formArr(superset,subset);



function formArr(superset,subset){
var newArr = [];
for(var i =0;i< superset.length;i++){        
   if(subset.indexOf(superset[i].number)!=-1){ 
      newArr.push(superset[i]); }
    }
   console.log(newArr);
   return newArr;
}
```

function formArr will return new array with required result.Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var newArr = [];
$(function () {
  var AllMateys =
          [{
             'names': 'Lot',
             'number': '0800695828'
           },
           {
              'names': 'Voltaire',
              'number': '0800069005'
           },
           {
              'names': 'SomeName',
              'number': '12345'
          }]


       var InvitedMateys = ["0800695828", "0800069005"];

      AllMateys.filter(function (obj) {
      if (InvitedMateys.indexOf(obj.number) > -1)
         newArr.push(obj);
       });

 });
```